# Python Pygame find angle between two points

Tags: python, pygame, angle

I am currently making a game which involves a sprite image to always face the mouse. I have looked everywhere for a function that does that, but I can't seem to find one.
Is there a way to calculate an angle of difference from one point to another?
Ex:

```
angleA_X, angleA_Y = (12, 52)
angleB_X, angleB_Y = (45, 11)

deltaX = angleB_X - angleA_X
deltaY = angleB_Y - angleA_Y

tan = deltaX/deltaY

formula = math.atan(tan)

formula = formula ** 2
formula = math.sqrt(formula)

formula = math.degrees(formula)

print(formula)
```

This would calculate the difference in the angle, but this does not return the right anwser. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: The `formula ** 2` and `math.sqrt(formula)` doesn't make sense. what do you have as formula to compute the angle? Isn't `tan⁡(angle)=y/x` the formula and then you need to reform it into `angle = atan2(y/x)`?

Comment: For points `A` and `B`, there are lines of length `|A.x - B.x|` and `|A.y - B.y|` that define a right angle triangle where the hypotenuse is a line segment between the points (There are actually two, pick one).  You can use the Law of Cosines to find the interior angle of that triangle.  That interior angle will be the angle from one of the axes centered at one of your points. (You chose which one when you chose which triangle to use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing some math operations that are not needed (such as `** 2` and `sqrt`), you just need `math.atan2` (this will yield the angle in radians between `A` and `B`):

```
math.atan2(angleA_Y - angleB_Y, angleA_X - angleB_X)
```

`math.atan2` has the benefit of also working when `deltaX == 0`.

Comment: I tested this in my program with `formula = math.degrees(((math.atan2(angleB_Y - angleB_Y, angleB_X - angleA_X))))` but that returned the awnser: 104.036243468, and i calculated it on my own, and got around 75. Did I do something wrong? EDIT- I put in the values angleA = (5, 2)  angleB = (4, 6)

Comment: @BobJohnson you have `angleB_Y - angleB_Y` which always gives `0`

Comment: @BobJohnson replace `A` with `B` in `atan2(angleA_Y - angleB_Y, angleA_X - angleB_X)` and you get around `-75`. BTW: `104.036243468  + around 75` gives `around 180`.

Comment: I fixed it and it still gives me the same anwser.

Comment: I tried `atan2(angleA_Y - angleB_Y, angleA_X - angleB_X)` with `angleA = (5, 2) angleB = (4, 6) ` and it gives me around `-75`

Answer (score 1):

`PyGame` has [pygame.math.Vector2()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) which have `angle_to()`

```
import pygame

angleA_X, angleA_Y = (12, 52)
angleB_X, angleB_Y = (45, 11)

a = pygame.math.Vector2(angleA_X, angleA_Y)
b = pygame.math.Vector2(angleB_X, angleB_Y)

zero = pygame.math.Vector2()

print( zero.angle_to(a-b) ) # 128.8298249049704
```

Comment: Tried to run it, pygame doesn't have attibute 'math'. What pygame version are you using?

Comment: pygame 1.9.2 on Linux - see link to documentation. It says it experimental and maybe your version doesn't have it

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** need an angle

```
angle = math.atan2(ymouse-ysprite, xmouse-xsprite)
```

if you rather need the sine and the cosine

```
dy, dx = ymouse-ysprite, xmouse-xsprite
r = math.hypot(dx, dy)
s, c = dy/r, dx/r
```